# How do I find the first URL in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextView implemented as:

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.isEditable = false
textView.dataDetectorTypes = .link
```

I know that setting the data detector type to link means that the text view will automatically find links, highlight them, and hyperlink them (make them tappable).

What I am trying to figure out is how to know whether or not the UITextView found at least one URL, and do something with that first URL programmatically. I've considered using regex to try to find common URL formats, but I'd like consistency with the way Apple does the detection.

Is there a way to extract the URL from attributedText, or is there an even simpler way to do it?

I think it could be done with something like this:

```
textView.attributedText.attribute(.link, at: 0, effectiveRange: 0..textView.text.count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSDataDetector` like follows:

```
let text = "I usually search stuff on stackoverflow.com to find answers"
if let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue) {

    let matches = detector.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))

    for match in matches {
        guard let range = Range(match.range, in: text) else { continue }
        let url = text[range]
        print(url) // > stackoverflow.com
        // Here is the place where you can count your URLs or do whatever you want with it
    }

}
```

**NB:**
- Sample provided in Swift 4
- It might affect performance in case of long text
- This code wasn't tested with emoji and complex graphemes, so you should probably do it.

---

Read more in [Official `NSDataDetector` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector)

Comment: My testing shows that this works with `text.count` instead of `text.utf16.count`. It works with emojis.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDataDetector` and the `firstMatch` method like this.

```
let string = "Detecting first url from the string www.google.com and https://facebook.com"
do {
    let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let range = NSRange(string.startIndex..<string.endIndex, in: string)
    if let firstMatch = detector.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: range) {
        print(firstMatch.url) // prints www.google.com
    } else {
        print("No url deteched")
    }
} catch {
}
```